# ISO - Update file internally without remaking

Tags: windows-7, iso-image

Is there a way, on Windows 7, to update a file inside an ISO?

Right now I extract all the files, update the file, then re-create the ISO.

Comment: I see this question was migrated. Did you ever want to do this **programmatically**?

Answer (score 2):

It must be said that the ISO file system format does not support the concept of rewriting or inline-modification. So even if you find an utility (like [UltraIso](http://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/), a shareware utility) that enables you to modify an ISO with a drag&drop style, it will ultimately rebuild the ISO to a temporary file and write it back to the original file.

ISO is meant for non-rewritable optical media like CD,DVD or BD-ROM. All files are consistent and allocated in contiguous spaces. In order to explain what you **cannot** with ISO, let me tell you what you **can** with regular hard disk drives and UDF file system (used by rewritable media). A normal hard disk's file system supports the concept of **file fragmentation** to allow a file that is larger the size of the largest continuous block to be stored in non-contiguous blocks. This feature exists because a hard disk, during normal operation, continuously writes new data and erases old data.

ISO doesn't simply support that.

Comment: Though I have no reason to specify, let me say I'm **not** affiliated with UltraIso

Answer (score 1):

[ISO Master](http://www.littlesvr.ca/isomaster/) is now available for Windows. It doesn't *quite* do what you ask, but it skips the extraction part.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.poweriso.com/ is a cheap software that will let you do it.